# Unable to publish .hyper file to Tableau site but hyper publish python code does not throw any error

Tags: python, tableau-api, hyper-api

I am trying to publish 686MB .hyper file to tableau server with user token value and token value, but from the logs I could see the file getting published but that file is not getting received on tableau server.

With same code I had published 191MB file to tableau server with same token credentials and it was received at tableau end.

Can anyone suggest anything on this?

I tried by changing hyper extract file name.

I am expecting to publish 686MG file to tableau server

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to publish 686MB hyper file to tableau server